# Is there any way to find probability of marcov chain when the time is same?

Tags: statistics, stochastic-processes, markov-chains

I am just wondering if I am given P(Xn=1 given that Xn=0) (Usual One Marcov chain)

Can you find this probability using transition matrix?

Comment: Are you sure you wrote this correctly? Because right now, your condition is that $X_n$ is $0$, so it is impossible for it to also be $1$. Perhaps you meant $P(X_n=1|X_{n-1}=0)$?

Comment: Question is that I am given Zn=(Xn-1, Xn) having the four states (0.0) (0.1) (1.0) (1.1), where Xn has two-state Markov chain. I am asked to find out transition probability matrix for Zn.